# Flutter: Invalid date format 24-09-2022

Tags: flutter, dart

```
// for date comparison
                              DateTime stdt = DateTime.parse(postList.startDate.toString());
                              DateTime endt = DateTime.parse(postList.endDate.toString());
                              DateTime crdt = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now()) as DateTime;



                              if (stdt.isAtSameMomentAs(endt)){
                                if(stdt.isBefore(crdt)){
                                  setState(() {
                                    ComparisonText = "Past";
                                    ContainerColor = Colors.red;
                                  });
                                }
                                else if (stdt.isAfter(endt)){
                                  setState(() {
                                    ComparisonText = "Upcoming";
                                    ContainerColor = Colors.yellow;
                                  });
                                }
                                else{
                                  setState(() {
                                    ComparisonText = "Ongoing";
                                    ContainerColor = Colors.yellow;
                                  });
                                }
                              } else{
                                if(stdt.isBefore(crdt)){
                                  if(endt.isBefore(endt)){
                                    setState(() {
                                      ComparisonText = "Past";
                                    });
                                  }
                                } else if (stdt.isAtSameMomentAs(endt)){
                                  setState(() {
                                    ComparisonText = "Ongoing";
                                  });
                                }else{
                                  setState(() {
                                    ComparisonText = "Upcoming";
                                  });
                                }
                              }
```

I have custom date format and I want to compare date.

I am new in flutter and I want compare date for showing schedule is past, upcoming or is Ongoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need specify the timeformat before parsing.
So you could try replacing

```
DateTime stdt = DateTime.parse(postList.startDate.toString());
DateTime endt = DateTime.parse(postList.endDate.toString());
```

with

```
DateTime stdt = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(postList.startDate.toString())); 
DateTime endt = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(postList.endDate.toString()));
```

Comment: I recommend this answer because that resolve the error

Comment: thanks for answer, after updating code i got following error.
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Comment: 'postList' this varible giveing me all data of api...Start date format from api is 24-09-2022.
please help me to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

`DateFormat().format(` returns a string .

You have to parse the string to date .

```
final formattedString =DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now());
final myDate = DateTime.parse(formattedString)
```

Comment: i am getting following error
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime crdt =
      DateTime.parse(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()));
```

Format used in your code - `'dd-MM-yyyy'`

Please take a look at this for accepted formats for parsing Dates -  [https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html#:~:text=Examples%20of%20accepted%20strings%3A](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html#:%7E:text=Examples%20of%20accepted%20strings%3A)

Edit: please add following library to make it work - **[intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install)** and import the following

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Comment: DateTime stdt = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse(postList.startDate.toString()); //DateTime.parse(postList.startDate.toString());
                              DateTime endt = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse(postList.endDate.toString());
                              DateTime crdt = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()) as DateTime;

i have write following code but same error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast"

Comment: @TakiRajani I forgot this --- please also add following library to make it work - **[intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install)** and import this `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`

Comment: Yes its allready added.its solved thanks for helping

Comment: Glad to be of help. It would be really helpful if you mark the answer accepted. @TakiRajani